# Why did Yirella do this with Uma, Doony, and the water?

Tags: salvation

> Uma and Doony knelt obediently by her side. Her head was well above the surface, but the water closed over their scalps.

I didn't understand the reason for this course of action. What was it supposed to free the subject from?

Comment: I've tried to give this a bit of a better title but I haven't read the book so feel free to correct it if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Being specific about the question could be a spoiler to someone who's reading the book but has not finished.

Comment: Titles should still on the most part explain what the question is about. Literally naming the work and saying "it could be a spoiler" is unhelpful to everyone because no one has anyway of knowing a) what the question is and b) what the spoiler is so they don't know if they should hover over it or not. The fact that a character does something to two other characters is hardly a spoiler in my mind. However, if it is feel free to come up with a better title but it ___needs___ a better one than what is there now. Also you should tag this with the work tag as I did but you rolled back.

Comment: I understand. I've tried to balance asking what I want without revealing too much. Will let future edits persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ‘She liberated herself’ Alexandre said ‘the only way she could’

Yirella is simply... not fit for the kind of life she was raised for. It is not about not being able to perform; she does excel at it. It’s simply not what she expects from life, so she runs away from it by getting rid of her Muncs. Without them she is allowed to look for other horizons, at the price of being partially outcast.

Comment: She doesn't leave Juloss. She doesn't leave her cohort. She doesn't leave Alexandre. And it is unclear how the muncs are holding her back. What is the relationship with the muncs that is restrictive? Maybe there really isn't more to it than meets the eye, but it was the only thing in the book that I really didn't get.

Comment: My understanding is muncs are not holding her back, but tying her to her designated task. With them, she has no options, she will be not allowed out, she will be allowed nothing but to live the scripted life of the cohort. Without them, she is free, she has no value or place anymore, and will be allowed anything except her old role.

Comment: That makes sense. She cannot be what she was born and raised and intended to be if she doesn't have the muncs. Thank you.

Comment: Good answer, I would add that she loved them the way they were and didn't want them to change. She wasn't supposed to have a choice in the matter so she created the only choice she could.